# p-table primeng edit with reactive form

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-reactive-forms, primeng

I created a table using primeng's table component with reactive form.
The task table will have only one column with the task name and it will be editable.

When clicking on the editing icon and typing a letter, the editing field is closed. It doesn't let you type more than one letter.

https://primeng-tablepage-demo-jjsnkl.stackblitz.io

I need the user to be able to edit the tasks.

Can anyone help?